# Laravel controller throwout error and not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel.

I used **way generator** to create laravel controller view and model, and it has default values for each item, But when I am going to see that with browser it is not working and showing an Error.

controller (***PostsController.php***):

```
class PostsController extends \BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return View::make('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }
 }
```

View (**posts/index.blade.php**):

```
This is index view
```

model (**post.php**)

```
class Post extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // 'title' => 'required'
    ];

    protected $primarykey='user_id';

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = [];

}
```

and this is route:

```
Route::resource('posts','postsController',array('except'=>array('show')));
```

when I type **localhost:8000/posts/index**, Laravel return an error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

**What is the problem?**

Comment: Do you have a [route](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing)?

Comment: @lukasgeiter now I edited

Comment: Try running in your command line (in the Laravel app directory) `php artisan routes` and see what routes were generated by the route resource definition. The **/index** part is not needed within the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats becouse you type **localhost:8000/posts/index**  as URL in browser, Just remove **index**

> localhost:8000/posts